# What is wrong in the Swift block syntax below?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, syntax, ios8, block

I am integrating AWS S3 service in my Swift based project but I stuck in the sysntax below as there is no description for the usage of API with Swift so I was trying to convert the code by myself.

```
transferManager.download(downloadRequest).continueWithExecutor(BFExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: 
{ (task:BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in
            println("test")
        })
```

I am getting following error!

```
Type '()' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
```

Comment: Are you sure that BFTask!? needs both exclamation and questionmark?

Comment: Isn't the problem that you does not return anything? It expects an AnyObject!.

Comment: looks like a bug in Xcode/Swift to me.  block must be of type 'BFContinuationBlock' which is defined as 'typedef id(^BFContinuationBlock)(BFTask *task);'  so, in theory 'withBlock: { task in ...}' or '-> Void' should work.  Can you switch to continueWithSuccess or continueWithhError ?

Comment: - (instancetype)continueWithExecutor:(BFExecutor *)executor
                       withBlock:(BFContinuationBlock)block;
This is the method I want to use with Swift! But I stuck in the block Syntax!

Comment: @SébastienStormacq 
"Can you switch to continueWithSuccess or continueWithhError ? –"
-------Yes I can switch to them but can you please provide me the syntax in Swift?

Comment: done already, see answer below :-)

Comment: If the answer below is correct, can you mark it as such ? This would help other customers having the same question and looking for answers. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what the problem is but switching to the regular `continueWithSuccess` works. Should you need the block to be execute on a thread, you can use grand central dispatch inside your block.

For example, if you need the block to be executed on the main UI Thread, you can write

```
        transferManager.download(downloadRequest).continueWithSuccessBlock({
            (task: BFTask!) -> BFTask! in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                println("test")
            })
            return nil
        })
```

The dispatch ... is only required when you want to run the block on a separate thread.

Comment: Normal, I wrote this in Dec 2014, Swift 3 did not exist at that time :-)